# How to ignore launchers of AndroidManifest.xml of a library project

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher, library-project

I have two Android projects A and B.
A uses B as a reference project,
and B might be a standalone project or a library project for A.
So A's manifest has a launcher and so does B's.

When building project A, "manifestmerger.enabled=true" is used to merge all attributes in B's manifest.
Thus, I got two launchers in app list of my device, one will launch A and the other will launch B.

My question is, may I ignore B's launcher setting?
I just need A's launcher for project A, and also want to keep B's launcher if I want to build B in standalone.

Thanks you.